# How to use with.columns in LazyGroupBy object in polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to calculate the difference of lag variable group by `id` variable. However,

when I tried to run the following code:

```
ad.v2.groupby('id').with_columns(
      diff = pl.col('Movement_Time_clear') - pl.col('Movement_Time_clear').diff()
)
```

A warning was popped:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'LazyGroupBy' object has no attribute 'with_columns'
```

What was the cause of the warning?

Comment: What it says on the tin, [`LazyGroupBy`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/group_by.html) doesn't have a `with_columns` function. Did you mean `agg`?

Comment: If the issue is resolved with agg then you should make that an answer rather than to edit the answer into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Wayoshi' s reminder, I should use `agg` instead of `with.columns`...

The updated code is as below:

```
ad.v2.groupby('id').agg(
      diff = pl.col('Movement_Time_clear') - 
             pl.col('Movement_Time_clear').shift()
                    ).collect()
```